# YouTube extract audio with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web

Is there a way to access audio track from YouTube video using Web Audio API?

Is there a way to load parts or whole YouTube video using `<audio>` or `<video>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

i dont think so - you are able to embed videos via `<iframe>`, but there is no option to extract and embed music out of youtube videos.

Comment: videoconverter.cc :)